# What are the steps to create AJAX pop up form in yiiframework?

Tags: ajax, forms, yii

I just started learning AJAX and Yiiframework. What are the steps to create AJAX pop up form in Yii?

Thank you.

Comment: Open the popup, bring over the content of the form with ajax, show it in the popup, close the popup after you submit the form.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask you do not show any code, nor does this show that you put any effort into ie before asking.

Comment: @MihaiP. I did a lot of effort and search but it is complicated to put all of my effort in this question so I just made it simple. I just need simple answer or hint. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yiu can use CJuiDialog, this code is taken from the references http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiDialog this link may also be helpful to you for configuration. http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

```
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
'id'=>'mydialog',
// additional javascript options for the dialog plugin
'options'=>array(
    'title'=>'Dialog box 1',
    'autoOpen'=>false,
),
));

echo 'dialog content here';

$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');

// the link that may open the dialog
echo CHtml::link('open dialog', '#', array(
'onclick'=>'$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;',
));
```

Comment: @sabsab Glad it helped, you can upvote it yourself too